# Reference request: showing that solution of an Ito SDE stays bounded with positive probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Assume that we have a (well-posed) Ito SDE of the form $$\mathrm{d} X_t = b(X_t)\,\mathrm{d} t + \sigma(X_t)\,\mathrm{d}W_t $$ where $b \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, $\sigma \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$, and $W_t$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. I am wondering under what kind of assumptions on the drift $b$ and the diffusion $\sigma$ can we show that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{t\geq 0} \|X_t\| \leq R\right) > 0$$ for some constant $R < \infty$? Or in other words, under what kind of assumptions on the drift $b$ and the diffusion $\sigma$ can we show that there is a positive probability such that the trajectory of $X_t$ does not leave some large enough balls? Currently I am only aware of the so-called **Stroock-Varadhan support theorem** showing that solutions of certain Ito SDEs stay within certain (large enough) finite balls almost surely for all time. But I am not aware of any literature which are related to my question. I would appreciate any pointers to contemporary research papers or lecture notes.

Comment: Would Feller's test for explosions be what you are looking for?

Comment: @user6247850 Can you provide a link to some notes that explain the concept that you suggested?

Comment: I think that [these notes](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/1185/docs/MATH_606/OneD-Diffusions.pdf) have a fairly concise description of the test.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a close look at it!